# content type application/x-www-form-urlencoded vs text/xml

Tags: asp.net, httpwebrequest

In my application while making a `HttpWebRequest` we were till now using content type as `application/x-www-form-urlencoded` since it just had a URL and a query string but now I need to  post some XML data also. So I added the XML data in the request stream as bytes. My question is:

- Do I need to change the contenttype to `text/xml`
- and if I do so, what will happen to query string part?

Although I tested with both the content type and it works fine but I need to understand the implications.  The URL is like `http:\\somewebsite?someid="test"`
while sending the request.

```
            //myHttpWebRequest.ContentType = "application/x-www-form-urlencoded";
            myHttpWebRequest.ContentType = "text/xml";
            string responseTxt = null;
            using (myWriter = myHttpWebRequest.GetRequestStream())
            {
                myWriter.Write(xmlbytes, 0, xmlbytes.Length);
            }
```

While reading the data from the request

```
            someid = context.Request.QueryString["someid"].ToString();

                using (StreamReader rsp = new StreamReader(context.Request.InputStream))
                {
                    xml = rsp.ReadToEnd();
                }
```